# Raspberry Pi 3 bluetooth pairing issue with tablet

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to establish a bluetooth communication between my tablet (either a Galaxy Tab 2 mini or GAlaxy Tab A so android 4 or 5 and Bluetooth 3.0 or 4.0).

When I try to pair my Raspberry Pi and my tablet, it returns the following error :
"Connection failed : No usable services on this device"

But one of my colleague successfully paired his phone with the Raspberry (it is an old Blackberry from 2011 running Bluetooth 2.1)

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue, it's very important to my project (using the tablet as a remote for my raspberry, wifi is forbidden in the place I will use this system)

Thank you for your answers

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a SP profile to the Pi. Edit the following file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service
```

Find the following line and add a compatibility flag '-C' to the end:

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -C
```

Additionally, add the following line after the above:

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sdptool add SP
```

Save and reboot. Try removing the device then repairing and trusting the device with bluetoothctl.

Then connect to the device with terminal via:

```
sudo rfcomm watch hci0
```

or

```
sudo rfcomm connect 0 <bluetooth address> 1
```

If that doesn't work you can also try adding pi to the lp group

```
sudo adduser pi lp
```

EDIT:

Recently I have created a Repo on GitHub that sets the Pi up as an Audio Receiver that allows for auto pairing of bluetooth devices, sets up airplay for iDevice users, and allows auxillary line input. The installation works great on the latest raspbian, it is best to use a fresh install. There are two versions, one that is a Home version that uses an existing wireless network for the AirPlay, the other is a Car version that creates its own Wireless Access Point without internet so that the iDevice can use AirPlay. It would be easy enough to add a hotspot for internet access as well.

In terms of this specific topic, the bluetooth works flawlessly and allows for users to control the bluetooth volume with their device.

REPO: https://github.com/BaReinhard/Raspberry-Pi-Audio-Receiver-Install-Car-Install

Comment: These appear to be the instruction for configuring a printer? Certainly did not work for me (same problem as OP)

Comment: Can you explain what those commands does? I.e. `sdptool add SP` and `bluetoothd -C`?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem myself before when I tried to connect my PC to my RPi 3. Basically what's happening here is that whenever your Pi connects to a device via Bluetooth, it checks if it can interact with that device.

If it can't interact, the Pi will throw up an error and disconnect because there's no point in connecting to a device that you can't interact with. The likely reason the pairing worked with your colleague is that the RPi *can* interact with your colleague's BlackBerry, so the RPi won't throw up an error.

You'll probably have to make your program first, install it on your tablet, and *then* try to connect to your RPi, so it will see the program and not disconnect because of no available services.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this problem the following way:

- Pair phone with raspberry pi
- Raspberry shows error
- Go to bluetooth settings on phone
- Open settings of paired raspberry pi device
- Enable audio and phone

Now your phone should be pairing just fine.